# How do I monitor MongoDB mapreduce?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, monitoring, mapreduce, mongoid

I have a log analyzing application. When users upload a file, it automatically begins to mapreduce it to generate reports. These files are big, so it can take some time. How do I monitor the mapreduce process so that I can indicate that a certain file is still being processed and be able to indicate when it's completed?

I can already mark a file as in process just before I kick off the process, but I can't seem to figure out how to run a callback when the mapreduce is over to indicate that it's complete.

I am currently using Rails with Mongoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Mongoid very well -- is its map-reduce helper not a blocking call? Or are you backgrounding it somehow?

[Per the docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Viewing+and+Terminating+Current+Operation), you can view all the current operations on your database by querying `db.$cmd.sys.inprog`, which will show information about current map-reduce jobs as well as "ordinary" queries. You might be able to find a way to identify which particular job is running based on its `query` or `out` parameters.

Comment: Yes, it turns out it is a blocking call. I didn't notice because I was calling it in a function that was used asynchronously.